# OpenCV usb uvc extension units for camera input

Tags: opencv, camera, usb, uvc

So i'm tying to get usb uvc extension units working with opencv.  I've tried looking for extension units, vendor specific units or XU units and nothing has shown up.

Does opencv has this ability.

Comment: you should introduce what "UVC extensions" and "extension units" are. -- I looked that up. that's quite close to hardware. use system APIs (dshow/msmf, V4L, ...) directly.

Comment: So i'm not a USB expert in any way but i can tell you what i know from reading the specification which you can read here.  https://www.usb.org/document-library/video-class-v15-document-set

Comment: The Extension Unit (XU) is the method provided by this specification to add vendor-specific  building blocks to the specification.  Although a generic host driver will not be able to determine what functionality is implemented in the Extension Unit, it shall report the presence of these extensions to vendor-supplied client 
software, and provide a method for sending control requests from the client software to the Unit, 
and receiving status from the unit.

Comment: So from a coding perspective it should just be a call to a lower level driver that's completely generic.  Like extension_unit_call(call,buffer).  All the other call to the camera are low level driver calls.  Like the exposure and contrast, so the extension unit is just a which the library doesn't inherently know what the size of the call is from the specification.

Comment: What i'm trying to do know is work with this guy library  https://github.com/joelpurra/node-uvc-control, which is a USB UVC wrapper for this library https://github.com/node-usb/node-usb  which is a generic USB driver library that works across linux and windows.  With the goal of trying to make a XU call with this and grab the frame with Opencv

Comment: that... is node.js. I have no idea how you could make that and OpenCV interoperate. best case, you can open the camera with whatever program, and send these XU control things from another program, so multiple programs "access" the usb device concurrently. I am not very positive that this should be the case.

Comment: So my end goal is to use a nodejs electron app with with a lot of image manipulation.  So i was hoping of using opencv for the image grab and the image manipulation.  After a lot of searching i found that this library libuvc could do the job. https://github.com/libuvc/libuvc. There's also a nice wrapper for it for javascript https://github.com/node-ffi-libraries/node-ffi-library-libuvc-v0.0.6

Answer (score 0):

At the moment it's my understanding that opencv doesn't support extension units.

So a alternative to opencv for grabbing a image and sending the extension unit commands is https://github.com/libuvc/libuvc.

It's cross platform and you should be able to easily pass your opencv mat to it.